# Collect multiple values out of JSON file via API in python, where some values can be none / []

Tags: python, json

I want to extract the values of scientific publications from the openalex API. However, since this API does not have complete values for all publications, the resulting JSON file is not always complete. If the file is complete, my code will run without issues. If the API does not have all information available, it can happen that the following result is found but cannot get interpreted: **"institutions":[]** instead of "institutions":**[{"id":"https://openalex.org/I2057...}{...}]**. As a result, I always get an "IndexError: list index out of range".

After an extensive search, I have already tried to solve the problem with the help of **try / except** or **if-queries** (if required, I can also provide them). Unfortunately, I did not succeed.

My goal is that in the charlist, in places where no information is available (**[]**), None or Null is entered. The goal is to program the code as performant as possible since I will have a high six-digit number of requests. This is, of course, already cleared with the API operator.

My code listed below already works for complete JSON files (upper magid_list) but not for incomplete entries **(2301544176)** as in the lower, not commented-out magid_list.

```
import requests
import json

baseurl = 'https://api.openalex.org/works?filter=ids.mag:'

#**upper magid_listworks without problems**
#magid_list = [2301543590, 2301543835]

#**error occur**
#**see page "https://api.openalex.org/works?filter=ids.mag:2301544176" no information for institution given**
magid_list = [2301543590, 2301543835, 2301544176]

def main_request(baseurl, endpoint):
    r = requests.get(baseurl + endpoint)
    return r.json()

def parse_json(response):
    charlist = []
    pupdate = data['results'][0]['publication_date']
    display_name = data['results'][0]['display_name']
    for item in response['results'][0]['authorships']:
        char = {
        'magid': str(x),
        'display_name': display_name,
        'pupdate': pupdate,
        'author': item['author']['display_name'],
        'institution_id': item['institutions'][0]['id']
        }
        
        charlist.append(char)
    return charlist

finallist = []

for x in magid_list:
    print(x)
    data = main_request(baseurl, str(x))
    finallist.extend(parse_json(main_request(baseurl, str(x))))

df = pd.DataFrame(finallist)

print(df.head(), df.tail())
```

If I can provide further information or clarification, let me know.

Attached you can find the full IndexError Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
f:\AlexPE\__programming\Masterarbeit.ipynb Cell 153 in <cell line: 37>()
     37 for x in list:
     38     print(x)
---> 39     finallist.extend(parse_json(main_request(baseurl, str(x))))
     41 df = pd.DataFrame(finallist)
     43 #data = main_request(baseurl, endpoint)
     44 #print(get_pages(data))
     45 #print(parse_json(data))

f:\AlexPE\__programming\Masterarbeit.ipynb Cell 153 in parse_json(response)
     20 display_name = data['results'][0]['display_name']
     23 for item in response['results'][0]['authorships']:
     24     char = {
     25     'magid': str(x),
     26     'display_name': display_name,
     27     'pupdate': pupdate,
     28     'author': item['author']['display_name'],
---> 29     'institution_id': item['institutions'][0]['id']
     30     }
     32     charlist.append(char)
     33 return charlist

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You need to check that a list element exists before you try to access it. Since you only access the 0th element of any of the lists, it's as simple as `if item['institutions']:`. If you need more help, please provide the entire traceback, there are several places where the IndexError may occur. Please, _never_ use `list` as a variable name, it is a very commonly used, built-in object and is clobbered when used as a variable name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Honestly, I've already tried the If statement but couldn't get it to work. It seems to me, unfortunately, as if I have a thinking error there. In the post, I have added the IndexError traceback, which I get in Python, now. Thanks for the hint with List. I changed this in the code directly, very good point.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with a result that doesn't have an item for institutions, but you can use `try: char = {...}; except IndexError: print("an exception occured"); else: charlist.append(char);`

Comment: Thank you, Smack, for your solution! The code runs through without an error message. However, is it possible that this function does not "skip" the complete magID but only fills the not present values with "Null"? The list is only a small part of a large dataset which currently only contains the magID. For many magIDs only the institution is missing, but the other data is present. Therefore the data is valuable to me and I will add the missing data manually or with the help of an algorithm at a later time. Every bit of data I don't have to add manually is very valuable to me.

Comment: When `item['institutions']` is an empty list, or `None`, **what should the result be**? For example, should the `'institution_id'` key disappear from `char`? Should it be given some placeholder value? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the existence of values before attempting to access them:

```py
def parse_json(response):
    charlist = []
    pupdate = display_name = None
    if data['results']:
        pupdate = data['results'][0].get('publication_date')
        display_name = data['results'][0].get('display_name')
    for item in response['results'][0]['authorships']:
        institution_id = None
        if item['institutions']:
            institution_id = item['institutions'][0].get('id')
        char = {
        'magid': str(x),
        'display_name': display_name,
        'pupdate': pupdate,
        'author': item['author']['display_name'],
        'institution_id': institution_id
        }
        
        charlist.append(char)
    return charlist
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That slight difference in the code made it work! Thank you all!